# Contar vocales de una cadena en PHP7

Tags: php, string, revisión-de-código, depuración

Tengo el siguiente enunciado: He de contar los caracteres totales de una cadena, contar el número total de vocales, y el número de veces que aparece cada vocal.
Yo me pierdo un poco y lo he hecho sin bucle while. Tampoco puedo usar arrays.
El error que me da al querer contar vocales por separado es:

```
Warning: substr() expects parameter 2 to be integer, string given in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pruebaexamen/ejercicio1.php on line 5

Warning: substr() expects parameter 2 to be integer, string given in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pruebaexamen/ejercicio1.php on line 6

Warning: substr() expects parameter 2 to be integer, string given in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pruebaexamen/ejercicio1.php on line 7

Warning: substr() expects parameter 2 to be integer, string given in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pruebaexamen/ejercicio1.php on line 8

Warning: substr() expects parameter 2 to be integer, string given in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pruebaexamen/ejercicio1.php on line 9
```

El código **PHP**:

```
<?php
    $texto = $_POST['texto'];
        $caracteres = strlen($texto);
        $vocales = substr_count($texto, 'a')+substr_count($texto, 'e')+substr_count($texto, 'i')+substr_count($texto, 'o')+substr_count($texto, 'u')+substr_count($texto, 'A')+substr_count($texto, 'E')+substr_count($texto, 'I')+substr_count($texto, 'O')+substr_count($texto, 'U');
        $a = substr_count($texto, 'a') + substr($texto, 'A');
        $e = substr_count($texto, 'e') + substr($texto, 'E');
        $i = substr_count($texto, 'i') + substr($texto, 'I');
        $o = substr_count($texto, 'o') + substr($texto, 'O');
        $u = substr_count($texto, 'u') + substr($texto, 'U');
        echo "El número total de caracteres es $caracteres <br/>";
        echo "El total de vocales es $vocales <br/>";
        echo "El numero de letras a (mayúsculas incluidas) es $a <br/>";
        echo "El numero de letras e (mayúsculas incluidas) es $e <br/>";
        echo "El numero de letras i (mayúsculas incluidas) es $i <br/>";
        echo "El numero de letras o (mayúsculas incluidas) es $o <br/>";
        echo "El numero de letras u (mayúsculas incluidas) es $u <br/>";
?>
```

Comment: Que error recibes?

Comment: Lo he puesto en la pregunta, pero el script me va bien

Comment: Te has equivocado, has puesto substr en lugar de substr_count

Comment: Qué fallo más tonto, gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu código pero "correcto".
Te habias equivocado poniendo `substr`, no `substr_count`

PHP:

```
<?php
    $texto = $_POST['texto'];
        $caracteres = strlen($texto);
        $vocales = substr_count($texto, 'a')+substr_count($texto, 'e')+substr_count($texto, 'i')+substr_count($texto, 'o')+substr_count($texto, 'u')+substr_count($texto, 'A')+substr_count($texto, 'E')+substr_count($texto, 'I')+substr_count($texto, 'O')+substr_count($texto, 'U');
        $a = substr_count($texto, 'a') + substr_count($texto, 'A');
        $e = substr_count($texto, 'e') + substr_count($texto, 'E');
        $i = substr_count($texto, 'i') + substr_count($texto, 'I');
        $o = substr_count($texto, 'o') + substr_count($texto, 'O');
        $u = substr_count($texto, 'u') + substr_count($texto, 'U');
        echo "El número total de caracteres es $caracteres <br/>";
        echo "El total de vocales es $vocales <br/>";
        echo "El numero de letras a (mayúsculas incluidas) es $a <br/>";
        echo "El numero de letras e (mayúsculas incluidas) es $e <br/>";
        echo "El numero de letras i (mayúsculas incluidas) es $i <br/>";
        echo "El numero de letras o (mayúsculas incluidas) es $o <br/>";
        echo "El numero de letras u (mayúsculas incluidas) es $u <br/>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para no complicarse con tanto código te recomiendo hacer un regex:

```
return preg_match_all('/[aeiou]/i',$str,$matches);
```

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT:** Tu código funciona bien porque estás usando `substr_count` para las minúsculas pero estás intentando hacer solo `substr` para las mayúsculas. Por eso te da WARNING, porque el método `substr` necesita dos parámetros enteros y no un String. También tendrás que quitar las etiquetas `<\br>`.

Tu código corregido sería:

```
<?php
    $texto = "oapresoiresoihriohesoirejsroijes";
    $caracteres = strlen($texto);
    $vocales = substr_count($texto, 'a')+substr_count($texto, 'e')+substr_count($texto, 'i')+substr_count($texto, 'o')+substr_count($texto, 'u')+substr_count($texto, 'A')+substr_count($texto, 'E')+substr_count($texto, 'I')+substr_count($texto, 'O')+substr_count($texto, 'U');
    $a = substr_count($texto, 'a') + substr_count($texto, 'A');
    $e = substr_count($texto, 'e') + substr_count($texto, 'E');
    $i = substr_count($texto, 'i') + substr_count($texto, 'I');
    $o = substr_count($texto, 'o') + substr_count($texto, 'O');
    $u = substr_count($texto, 'u') + substr_count($texto, 'U');
    echo "El número total de caracteres es $caracteres \n";
    echo "El total de vocales es $vocales";
    echo "El numero de letras a (mayúsculas incluidas) es $a \n";
    echo "El numero de letras e (mayúsculas incluidas) es $e \n>";
    echo "El numero de letras i (mayúsculas incluidas) es $i \n";
    echo "El numero de letras o (mayúsculas incluidas) es $o \n";
    echo "El numero de letras u (mayúsculas incluidas) es $u \n";
?>
```

---

**Respuesta original**: No había leído que un requerimiento era no usar arrays. En caso de que se puedan usar, dejo el ejemplo por si le puede ser de utilidad a alguien en un futuro.

No es necesario que hagas ningún bucle while.

Con las propias funciones de PHP puedes realizar lo siguiente:

```
<?php
      $cadena = "oapresoiresoihriohesoirejsroijes";

      //Divides la cadena por carácteres y lo almacenas en un array.
      $array = str_split($cadena); 

      //Estableces cuales son los valores que te quieres quedar
      $vocales = array('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'); 

      //Con array_filter quitas los valores que no quieres en tu array.
      //O mejor dicho, te quedas sólo con los que necesitas.
      $arrayQuitandoConsonantes = array_filter($array, function($val) use ($vocales) {
          return in_array($val, $vocales);
      });

      //Muestras la cantidad de veces que está contenida cada vocal
      print_r(array_count_values($arrayQuitandoConsonantes));
```

Para esta cadena, el output correspondiente será:

```
Array
(
    [o] => 6
    [a] => 1
    [e] => 5
    [i] => 5
)
```

Comment: El caso es que mi script funciona, pero me da warning

Comment: Voy a probar tu código  a ver, pero el enunciado decía sin arrays. Si funciona votaré positivo igualmente

Comment: Por favor, ¿alguien me puede explicar el voto negativo?